# Where can I find a metal one of these online?

Tags: hardware, brackets

I need something like the following but made of metal.
[image]

Comment: I hope you do realize that insufficient information has been provided. No one would be able to help you shop because we do not know if you need it to be copper, steel, brass, aluminium, gold, silver or platinum. We also do not know if it is supposed to be plated, painted, anodized or raw metal. Also missing are dimensions for size of holes, distance between holes, height of bracket, width of bracket, length of channel under bracket and thickness of bracket. It would also be extremely helpful to know what you need to use this bracket for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [source for a metal bracket](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BO9NFI) like you want.

[image]